# What is the difference between localName() and name().localName()?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

In the AS3 XML class there appears to be two ways of getting the `localName` of an element:

```
oXml.localName()
```

and

```
oXml.name().localName()
```

Is there any difference between the two? Is one generally preferred over the other?

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#name()   http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#localName()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen in the documentation this will ultimately resolve to the same value in the second case you're making two method calls in the first only one.  In the second case you're getting an object that contains a fully qualified name, if you select the name off of that it's the same as just selecting the simple name from the XML object directly from what I can tell.